# Using Ohm's law in a loop to find current provided by a voltage source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I just wanted to know whether you could use ohm's law to find the current in a loop  from a voltage source. The circuit in particular is the following:

[image]

I needed to find V1 using KCL, so I applied KCL to V1 and the other two relevant nodes. I think that my equations are correct, but I neede to find ia and i, so my question is, can you do the following to find ia:

V=(ia)R

ia=V/R

ia=10/(10+40) -> adding the resistances of the resitors in series for the loop with the 10V voltage source.

ia=1/5

Therefore, the voltage of the dependent voltage source:
V=20ia

V=4

Therefore, I tried the same thing to calculate i and got i as 1/15.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis). You use KCL plus an equation for I vs V for each branch in the circuit. With a little bit of elaboration (for example you can't write an I(V) equation for a voltage source), you have the same procedure that SPICE simulators use to solve circuits.

Comment: Key point: You need to define which node in your circuit is ground (or "common") otherwise you can't ask "what's the voltage at V1?". You can only ask what's the voltage at V1 relative to some other node in the circuit.

Comment: The ground is defined as the base of the circuit

Comment: You need to show that in your schematic using a ground symbol, or you'll be the only one who knows it. Please edit your question to include all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: In the diagram, what is 20ia?